# How to determine value changes according to another columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Below table includes non-unique id, money value and dates/times.

```
id_1   value_1     value_time       id_version      Version_time
138    250         09-SEP-14        595             02-SEP-14
140    250         15-SEP-14        695             01-AUG-14
140    300         30-DEC-14        720             05-NOV-14   
233    250         01-JUN-15        800             16-MAY-15
```

As you can see id_1, id_version and time columns can change in table but value_1 may stay the same.

I know that if id_1 is same in rows, value_1 can only change according to id_version. But there are too many id_version in the table. And I know that it changes according to id_version, but i don't know the exact change time of it.

So firstly I have to decide, which id_version and id_version time cause the value change group by id_1.

But again id_1 is not uniqe, and id may change but value stays the same :)

<sub>editor: From OP's comment - Begin</sub>
Here is the desired result example i want to get the first and second row not the third and fourth row.

```
| 140 | 250 | 15-SEP-14 | 695 | 01-AUG-14 |
| 140 | 300 | 31-DEC-14 | 725 | 07-NOV-14 |
| 140 | 300 | 05-JAN-14 | 740 | 30-NOV-14 |
| 140 | 300 | 30-DEC-14 | 720 | 05-NOV-14 |
```

<sup>editor: From OP's comment - End</sup>

Thanks in advance really need help in this situation.

Comment: Do you want to order your data set by id_1 and time? In which case the ORDER BY clause would produce that. An example of your desired output, and some rewording would help clarify your question.

Comment: Please add desired results and try to fix the explanation, which is very hard to follow.

Comment: Actually i want to order by id_1 and version time. So that i want know the exact time when the value change.  As i said there are too much version time but i don't know the exact version number that cause the value change.

Comment: [1]: http://i.imgur.com/GGuEGgc.jpg?1       Here is the desired result example i want to get the first and second row not the third and fourth row.

Comment: Please add your expected results to the question as text, not an image; and show how it relates to your sample data - you may need to expand the sample too. It is still very unclear what you mean. Do you want to only see the rows where value_1 changed for each id_1, perhaps?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input given so far (and processing just the data in the linked to picture - rather than the one in the current example data), the following should help to get you started:

```
SELECT
  TMin.id_1
  , TMin.value_1
  , TO_CHAR(TAll.value_time, 'DD-MON-RR') value_time
  , TMin.id_version
  , TO_CHAR(TMin.version_time, 'DD-MON-RR') version_time
FROM
  (SELECT
    id_1
    , value_1
    , MIN(id_version) id_version
    , MIN(version_time) version_time
  FROM T
  GROUP BY id_1, value_1
  ORDER BY id_1, value_1
  ) TMin
JOIN T TAll
  ON TMin.id_1 = TAll.id_1
  AND TMin.value_1 = TAll.value_1
  AND TMin.id_version = TAll.id_version
  AND TMin.version_time = TAll.version_time
ORDER BY TMin.id_1, TMin.value_1
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a1847/1).
Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.